# Moodle setting course of cloze questions

Tags: moodle

I am learning how to use Moodle. I have created 3 cloze questions in the question bank and added them to a course.

I then created a student account which successfully enrols on my course of 3 cloze questions successfully.

My problem concerns accessing the course. In both the admin and student modes, my course is listed under **courses** in the left-sidebar. When I click on my course name instead of seeing my questions, I get the following message:

```
News forum
General news and announcements

(No news has been posted yet)
```

I want to create questions, add them to a course and have those questions display ready to be answered by enrolled users who click on the course name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In moodle you need to add the questions to a quiz of particular course. So after created the questions, you need to create the quiz and add those created questions on quiz.

So the enrolled users will access that quiz when he/she would clicked on particular quiz of particular course.

Here is the link for [Create a quiz](https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Building_Quiz)